# Grails app not loading js and css from cloud front

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

This has to be some type of configuration issue, but I can't figure out what it is.  My grails app when deployed to elastic beanstalk will load my index.gsp and show an image.  Now this is a stripped down application with nothing but a single page.  The page has one image and I'm trying to load the css/js/image from cloudfront.  The image loads fine.

http://d55az6m6nudec.cloudfront.net/images/placeholder.jpg

Css + js do not load at all:

http://d55az6m6nudec.cloudfront.net/js/application.js

But as you can see the js comes from the same cloudfront and the URL is formatted the same.  When I inspect the webpage and click on the js or css files, I get redirected through cloudfront and the browser shows it's trying to load this URL:

http://awseb-e-m-awsebloa-1bzuvx2wx2h91-492777361.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/statichttp://d55az6m6nudec.cloudfront.net/js/application.js

So it's got the 'static' prefix in there, and I don't know what's going on.  Here are some of the relevant parts of my Config.groovy:

```
grails.resources.mappers.baseurl.enabled = true
```

I've tried this next line both commented on/off:

```
grails.resources.mappers.bundle.excludes = ['**/*']
```

Here is my base url:

```
grails.resources.mappers.baseurl.default = "http://d55az6m6nudec.cloudfront.net"
```

I have tried this on/off:

```
grails.resources.uri.prefix = ""
```

I have tried this with/without values:

```
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = []
```

and:

```
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*']
```

I'm running out of combinations, and at this point I'm just doing trial and error which is taking forever to figure out what should work.  I'm also using a load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was I did not have the grails.serverURL variable set for my production environment.  Now I'm not sure why this caused the error, but I redeployed with the server set and now the css and js files are loading fine.